# Is there a way to check Jenkins reboot history

Tags: jenkins

I was using the Restart Safely option in jenkins to restart the master after some running jobs completed.

However jenkins was unattended after that and now it's up and running. Is there a way to check when the master restarted in the form of jenkins reboot history (or something like ps -ef equivalent would also work in that I can see the process start time to get details of the restart).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will be in `/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log.log`.

Check for `Jenkins is fully up and running`  you should also see messages about the scheduled reboot.